# Loop through group and difference lags

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I have time-series data (`t`) that I want to loop through each `t` and take the difference of the previous five lags `t-1 ... t-5`.

This code works, but is inefficient. I'm not sure how to increase the performance and efficiency of the code.

**Sample data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as nr

dat = pd.DataFrame({'t': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'rnum': nr.rand(10)})
```

**Function**

```
def diff_n(idat):
    # Get t from group
    i = idat['t'].iat[0]

    # If one, nothing to difference
    if i == 1:
        return None

    # Get value to loop through and diff
    h1 = idat.groupby('t')['rnum'].mean().values

    # Subset dat (outside fn)
    h2 = dat[(dat.t < i ) & (dat.t >= i - 5)]

    # Combine data for return
    retdat = pd.DataFrame()

    # Loop through t-1 to last obs
    for j in range(max(h2.t), min(h2.t), -1):

        # Get value to difference from h1
        h3 = h2[h2.t == j].groupby('t')['rnum'].mean().values

        # Difference
        ndiff = (h3 - h1)

        # Build df and concat
        indat = pd.DataFrame({'t': [i], 'lag': i - j, 'diff': ndiff})
        retdat = pd.concat([retdat, indat])
    return retdat
```

**Groupby and apply the function to each t**

```
dat.groupby('t').apply(lambda x: diff_n(x))
```

**Output**

```
>>> dat.groupby('t').apply(lambda x: diff_n(x))
      t  lag      diff
t                      
2  0   2    1  0.440644
3  0   3    1 -0.284075
   0   3    2  0.156569
4  0   4    1  0.439154
   0   4    2  0.155079
   0   4    3  0.595723
5  0   5    1 -0.095552
   0   5    2  0.343602
   0   5    3  0.059527
   0   5    4  0.500171
6  0   6    1  0.296337
   0   6    2  0.200784
   0   6    3  0.639939
   0   6    4  0.355864
   0   6    5  0.796507
7  0   7    1 -0.749913
   0   7    2 -0.453576
   0   7    3 -0.549128
   0   7    4 -0.109974
   0   7    5 -0.394049
8  0   8    1  0.506379
   0   8    2 -0.243534
   0   8    3  0.052803
   0   8    4 -0.042749
   0   8    5  0.396405
9  0   9    1 -0.021761
   0   9    2  0.484618
   0   9    3 -0.265295
   0   9    4  0.031042
   0   9    5 -0.064510
10 0  10    1  0.409118
   0  10    2  0.387357
   0  10    3  0.893736
   0  10    4  0.143823
   0  10    5  0.440160
```

Comment: Does your `t` column always contain numbers in consecutive increasing order? Could you have this sequence `'t': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 8, 9, 2, 10, 5]` (repetitive numbers) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm not sure what you mean. But yes, the nature of the problem means `t` is in consecutive increasing order.

Comment: Grouping by `t` values with `dat.groupby('t')` implicitly indicates that there could repetitive values, but in that case - the above code will fail (`ValueError: arrays must all be same length` .+. `KeyError: 't'`). Sample input `'t': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. But if your `t` column is not supposed to contain duplicate values - then why grouping on `t` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, `t` will contain duplicate values because the `lag` variable is different across `t`. I use `groupby()` to get each `t`, then apply the function on `n` lags.

Comment: As I mentioned, your code will **not** work on this sample input `pd.DataFrame({'t': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'rnum': nr.rand(12)})`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry, I fixed the code so your sample input will work now.

Comment: It does not work with your fix, same errors

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry I didn't change the for loop groupby. Works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Toward better performance and functionality (reducing code run time twice)

Always give your identifier/variable/function a meaningful name.
Most of your identifiers/variables should be renamed to reflect the actual intention and purpose.
 A short sample of better naming:

- `dat` --> **`df`**
- `idat` --> **`group`**
- `i` variable, which is actually `t` value --> **`t`**
- `h1` variable, which is actually `rnum` mean value --> **`rnum_mean`**

and so on ... (see the final implementation below)

---

**`diff_n`** function

The number `5` serves as "subtraction factor" thus instead of hard-coding it it's better to make that factor adjustable and define it as default argument:

```
def diff_n(group, n=5):
```

Calling `.groupby('t')` in `idat.groupby('t')` and `h2[h2.t == j].groupby('t')` is redundant as the input/initial dataframe is already grouped by same `t` values (`dat.groupby('t').apply(lambda x: diff_n(x)`) and `diff_n` function will accept sub-dataframe having the **same** `t` column values but various `rnum` column values.

No need to `mean().values` as `mean()` is a reducing function and returns a single value.

Instead of generating a new dataframe and accumulate data with `pd.concat()` on each loop iteration - a single dataframe can be generated at once accepting a list of composed dictionaries.

---

The final optimized approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as nr

df = pd.DataFrame({'t': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'rnum': nr.rand(12)})

def diff_n(group, n=5):
    t, rnum_mean = group.t.iloc[0], group.rnum.mean()
    if t == 1:
        return None

    # Subset df (outside fn)
    diff_rows = df[(df.t < t) & (df.t >= t - n)]
    return pd.DataFrame([{'t': t,
                          'lag': t - i,
                          'diff': diff_rows[diff_rows.t == i].rnum.mean() - rnum_mean}
                         for i in range(max(diff_rows.t), min(diff_rows.t), -1)])


res = df.groupby('t').apply(lambda x: diff_n(x))
```

---

**Time performance comparison** (tested on randomly generated sequence of numbers for `rnum` column):

```
rnum_data = [0.32371336559866004, 0.10698919887971459, 0.7953413399540619,
             0.9868916409057458, 0.9441608945915095, 0.47072752314030053,
             0.4508488822488548, 0.028372702128714233, 0.87623218782289,
             0.16471466305535765, 0.1, 0.2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'t': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'rnum': rnum_data})
...
```

The old (initial) approach:

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("dat.groupby('t').apply(lambda x: diff_n(x))", globals=globals(), number=100))

5.156789435990504
```

The new approach:

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("df.groupby('t').apply(lambda x: diff_n(x))", globals=globals(), number=100))

2.5971586129890056
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for your effort. Much better performance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, nice code, very readable and good comments.

There are several improvements you can do:

1. Reindex your dataframe with `t`. You are writing a lot of times `.t`, if you will use `index` some of `pandas` index optimization will kick in and your code will be faster.
2. Do not do `concat` on only 2 items. Concatenate function will work much faster if you will just do all of the concatenation of all 5 elements at once.
3. Why do you need `h2`? Try to avoid unnecessary coping of the data frame. You can work on the original `h1` or even `idat` since your function does not change anything implicitly.
4. Use type annotations. Using type annotations can make the code run faster since the interpreter does not need to figure out what is the variable type. Also, probably even more important, it helps readability.